# Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DatabaseLayer' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

here the "DatabaseLayer" is a class inside app_code folder ,but when accessing the URL
I am getting

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DatabaseLayer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:

Line 14: 
Line 15:

```
Line 16:     DatabaseLayer db_obj = new DatabaseLayer();
Line 17:     BusinessLogic bl_obj = new BusinessLogic();
```

Line 18:

Source File: d:\hosting\10615831\html\eSchool\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 16

but the file i placed in correct way..please help me.

Comment: Is it under the same namespace?

Comment: yes but "DatabaseLayer" is a class file inside the appcode folder

Comment: It doesn't matter where it is as a file but it matters in what namespace it is placed. Check for the namespace and be sure you have the right usings in your namespace